# Adding facebook like button after facebook widget on same page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, facebook-like

I am using jquery to add a Facebook widget and "Like" button on a page.
I am using

```
$(window).load(function(){
     getWidget(//loads php file containing widget code)
});
$(window).load(function(){
    getButton(//loads php file containing like button code)
});
```

The problem is, either widget loads up or either like button but not both. Sometimes they show up together.

I tried adding some delay between the two, but it doesnt work as expected. Is it that once widget loads up you cannot load like button after that? (i am using HTML 5 versions of both).

Comment: That's not valid Javascript -- even when ignoring the pseudo-contents of the functions. Let's see some actual code, or we're just _guessing_ at what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The code above is not exactly what i m using. The code i use is valid. But the issue is only one of the facebook element loads up not both.

Comment: We are to take your word for it that the code is "valid", when you're asking for help fixing it because it's broken? Seriously?

Comment: Tomalak, i have given a snippet of code that i use. do help me out with the problem i have.

Comment: No, you haven't. As we've already agreed, that is _not_ valid Javascript code. How am I supposed to help you with code that I cannot see?

Answer (score 0):

What code is in the PHP file? You wan't to make sure you aren't loading the Facebook javascript file twice.

Comment: I think that might be the reason. Let me try removing one of the JavaScript.

Comment: I tried removing the <script>...</script> for Like button from the second php file. But still it doesnt help. How do i remove one of the javascript.